# Was the Anarchist Cookbook created by the FBI/CIA to sabotage insurgency?

Tags: history

My professor said that the Anarchist Cookbook (a collection of recipes for bombs, etc.) was created by the government, who inserted deliberate errors to make sure that budding insurgents would blow themselves up.

I thought the book was written by William Powell, now a schoolteacher, and that the errors were innocent mistakes.

I've found a [few](http://strangefamousrecords.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=38737&sid=da23906d602bafecc147b76cb2cad6df) [people](https://www.techdirt.com/articles/20150402/15274630528/fbi-uncovers-another-its-own-plots-senator-feinstein-responds-saying-we-should-censor-internet.shtml#c905) discussing this view on the internet. Is William Powell a front, or was he sponsored by the government in some way?

Comment: [Welcome to skeptics](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users). I'm afraid forums and comments do not constitute a notable claim. Please add a [notable claim](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2506/what-is-a-notable-claim) to prevent this question from getting closed.

Comment: You can find the FBI's files on the book at http://www.governmentattic.org/4docs/FBI-AnarchistsCookbook_1971-1999.pdf